# How does the order of coset aN in G/N and the order of the normal subgroup N determine the relation between the element a and the identity element?

Tags: group-theory

Here is the specific question.

Say the order of Normal subgroup N in G is x.
Say that aN has order y in quotient group G/N.
Show a^(xy) = e in group G.

I think I am missing some core concept and have no idea how to go about this.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Use MathJax formatting to mathematical expressions. See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given any $a\in G$, we may write it as $a=bn$ for some $n\in N$ (because the cosets of $N$ partition $G$). Therefore,  $aN=bN$, and we may consider both $a, b$ simultaneously. Now, having the order $y$ in $G/N$ means that $(aN)^y = N$, or that $(bn)^n \in N$. Since the order of $N$ is $x$, every $n'\in N$ satisfies $(n')^x = e$. We shall then choose $n' = (bn)^y$ to obtain $a^{xy} = (bn)^{xy} = (n')^y = e$.

Comment: Is is always the case that for any a ∈ N, where N is a normal subgroup, a will have order x in G if the order of N is x?

Comment: No. That is why there is the $y$ also, not just $x$. We need $aN$ to be of finite order to get $y$, and we need $N$ itself to be of finite order to get $x$. I can't think of any immediate example now, but I am fairly sure that the finite order of $N$ is not enough to make $aN$ be of finite order.

Comment: OK, @pickie_rick, I came up with a really dumb example. Let $N = \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}, G = \mathbb{Z}\oplus N$. If $a\in G$, then $a = (m, [n]_2)$, for some integers $m, n$, and $aN$ can be identified with $m$.If $m\neq 0$, then $a$ is of infinite order and no finite $y$ such that $(m, [n]_2)^y\in N$ can be found, even though $x=2$.